# Merge cells in VSCode jupyter notebook?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I found the recently updated Jupyter notebook support of VSCode very useful.

However, I can't figure out how to merge cells.

Is it possible at all? or will this feature land in the near future?

Answer (score 15):

In VSCode version 1.57.0-insider you can:

- merge the cells with the hotkey: `Alt`+`Windows`+`J`

See also: [How to split cell in VSCode Jupyter Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64673038/how-to-split-cell-in-vscode-jupyter-notebook/67673674#67673674)

Comment: Merge the cell with next cell shortcut: Alt+Windows+J. Merge cell with previous cell: Shift + Alt + Windows + J

Comment: In mac, it's `control` + `option` + `J`

Comment: For some stupid reason this command merges the cell below whatever you've selected as well (at least on my mac)... but considering the actual command is called "Notebook: Join With Next Cell" it seems intentional??

Comment: When I right-click on the left hand side of a cell, I get a cell action menu. I this menu, however, the provided keyboard shortcut for joining cells is `Alt` + `J`. I can confirm that adding the `Win` key makes the cell join work. What I don't understand is *why*. Did the developer simply forget to add the `Win` key to the listed shortcut key combinations, or is there another reason why the `Win` key  has to be added?

Comment: Strangely, on my mac it was `Fn+^+Opt+J`, while `join above` works with default `Shift+^+Opt+J` without `Fn`

Answer (score 7):

Here is a new option that allows you to select cells and merge them, see [v1.75 Release Notes: Join Selected Cells](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_75.md#join-selected-cells):

> Join Selected Cells
>
> We have added a new command Join Selected Cells
> (kb(`notebook.cell.joinSelected`)) to merge multiple selected cells
> into one cell.

It is unbound by default, but you could make a keybinding like this (in your `keybindings.json`) or use the Keyboard Shorts UI - search for `join selected`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+j",
  "command": "notebook.cell.joinSelected"
}
```

Comment: what would be a good `when` expression for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I hope the developers will include this feature in the near future.

Unfortunately, by now, there's no such option.

You can find an open issue regarding this feature [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/9073).

There's also an [epic](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/10496) which gathered all the issues and developments regarding the Jupyter notebook in VS Code