# How to split cell in VSCode Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

How can a Jupyter notebook cell be split in VSCode?  I.e., how to split a single cell with multiple lines into two cells with the top lines (above the cursor) in one cell and the bottom lines (below the cursor) in another cell?

I've tried `Cntrl` `Shift` `-` using the Daily Insiders Python Extension, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: For merging selected cells, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75278093/836330.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Ctrl Shift -` is for `zooming out the display` by default in VS Code. This feature has been put for a long time in Github, and the following is the request:

> [Jupyter Split Cell and Select Multiple Cells command](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/9073)

This issue is still open, although there's [Notebooks are getting revamped!](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/notebooks-are-getting-revamped/) existed, it's for [VS Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/), not our current using **VS Code**. Maybe the production group can improve it in the future.

Comment: For me, `Ctrl Shift -` doesn't do anything, but `Ctrl -` zooms out.  Interesting that the GitHub issue concludes with a link to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/notebooks-are-getting-revamped/ that says splitting/joining cells is now an option ... but I can't find them.

Comment: Cause it's provided by [Visual Studio Code Insider](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/), we're using Visual Studio Code. You can get the option **Open in Preview NoteBook Editor** from the Command Palette, but it doesn't have the real fucntion.

Comment: Ahhhh, it requires `code-insiders`  not just Daily Insiders for the Python Extension.  Make it an answer and I'll accept.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

In VSCode version 1.57.0-insider you can:

- split cells with the hotkey: `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`-`

See also: [Merge cells in VSCode jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809002/merge-cells-in-vscode-jupyter-notebook/67658420#67658420)

Comment: Newly released: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_75#_join-selected-cells

Answer (score 2):

`ctrl shift -` works for VSCode (version 1.66.2) on Mac (Monterey 12.3.1)

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to just put the cursor where you want to split and then use ctrl-shift dash.  If you try to highlight the section you want split out, as in normal Jupyter splitting, you will get the zoom behavior.